# In the constructor of WebRTC VideoSendStreamParameters, why is the config argument not passed by a reference?

Tags: c++, webrtc

In the constructor of WebRTC *VideoSendStreamParameters*, *config* argument is passed by a value(thus introducing a copy overhead), but *options* argument is passed by a reference.
Also the *config* member is initialized by *std::move(config)*.
I want to know why they designed like this.

The followings are scraped from Chromium source.

```
namespace webrtc {
...
class VideoSendStream {
  ...
  struct Config {
    ...
    Config() = delete;
    Config(Config&&);
    ... // It's followed by many data members.
  };
  ...
};
...
}



namespace cricket {
...
class WebRtcVideoChannel ... {
  ...
  class WebRtcVideoSendStream {
    ...
    struct VideoSendStreamParameters {
      VideoSendStreamParameters(
          webrtc::VideoSendStream::Config config,
          const VideoOptions& options, ...)
      ...
      webrtc::VideoSendStream::Config config;
      VideoOptions options;
      ...
    };
    VideoSendStreamParameters parameters_ ... ;
    ...
  };
  ...
};

WebRtcVideoChannel::WebRtcVideoSendStream::VideoSendStreamParameters::
    VideoSendStreamParameters(
        webrtc::VideoSendStream::Config config,
        const VideoOptions& options, ...)
    : config(std::move(config)),
      options(options), ... {}

WebRtcVideoChannel::WebRtcVideoSendStream::WebRtcVideoSendStream(
    ...
    webrtc::VideoSendStream::Config config,
    const VideoOptions& options, ...)
    : ...,
      parameters_(std::move(config), options, ...), ...
{
  ...  
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the config is modified during the lifetime of the stream. Already in the stream [constructor](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/main/media/engine/webrtc_video_engine.cc#2084) you have:

```cpp
parameters_.config.rtp.max_packet_size =
    std::min<size_t>(parameters_.config.rtp.max_packet_size, kVideoMtu);
```

And in [SetSendParameters](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/main/media/engine/webrtc_video_engine.cc#2273), for example:

```cpp
parameters_.config.rtp.rtcp_mode = *params.rtcp_mode;
```

When a class "owns" the data, it is a usual pattern to pass it by value and initialize the member with `std::move`. This is sometimes referred to as sink argument.

EDIT

Sorry, I missed the part that `VideoOptions` is also stored by value and is also modified in [SetVideoSend()](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/main/media/engine/webrtc_video_engine.cc#2153):

```cxx
parameters_.options.SetAll(*options);
```

With that, another explanation why `Config` is being moved, is that `Config` is intended to be mostly move-only type. [Its assign operator](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/main/call/video_send_stream.h#145) is deleted, copy constructor is private and `Copy()` function commented with:

> Mostly used by tests.  Avoid creating copies if you can.

Why is that? Can't really tell for sure. It was changed in [cc168360f413](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc.git/+/cc168360f41322332860cb075edeb1cde21aa473%5E!/#F35) as part of [Issue 5687: Refactor Encoder - MediaTransport layer to use rtc::VideoSink/Source interface](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=5687).

Comment: Can you explain why 'options' is passed by a reference? A VideoOptions instance is also owned by a VideoSendStreamParameters instance.

Comment: Sorry for another comment. Now I understand the merit of 'passing by value for constructors'. I guess that they cared to optimize Config class for move semantics but didn't care to optimize VideoOptions. Am I right?

Comment: You're right, "options" are also owned. As such I don't have better explanation than in the edit.